# Selenium Webdriver adding custom string to user-agent in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, user-agent

I have Selenium WebDriver setup using C#. I am using ChromeDriver. I have a requirement to append a custom string to the end of user-agent. I know I can do this

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddArgument(@"user-agent=""YOUR_USER_AGENT""");

Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The above code howerver completely replaces user-agent. What I want is just append my custom string to the end of actual user-agent, so that actual user-agent information will not be lost.

Is there anyway to get user-agent information?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok fine, what about this:

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String userAgent = (String) js.executeScript("return navigator.userAgent");
    System.out.println("user agent: " + userAgent);
```

Answer (score 0):

User agent by default is fixed by your browser installation, you can get it first from a website like http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/ 
and then do what you want.

Comment: Hi. My question is how do I get the name of user-agent programatically.